# Better design for initialization within constructor

Tags: java, oop

I have a class that looks something like this which acts as factory for clients based on credentials retrieved from credentials service. It builds clients one time and returns that on every call.

```
public class ClientFactory {
   private CredentialService credentialService;
   private ClientA clientA; 

   public ClientFactory(CredentialService credentialService){
      this.credentialService = credentialService;
      //initialization in constructor
      this.clientA = buildClientA(credentialService.getCredentials());
   }

   public ClientA getClientA(){
       return clientA;
   }

   /** Build new ClientA using crendentials*/
   private ClientA buildClientA(String credentials){
     return new ClientA(credentials);
   } 
}
```

Issue that I see with this is line 2 in the constructor which basically start using dependency 'credentialService' to initialize other dependencies immediately. If some other developer moves around order of code in constructor, it will start failing. Other option is too change method `getClientA()` to this.

```
   public ClientA getClientA(){
      if(clientA == null) {
        this.clientA = buildClientA(credentialService.getCredentials());
      }
       return clientA;
   }
```

But it has thread safety issues. Is there a better way to design above class which avoids concerns I highlighted above?

Thanks

Comment: `But it has thread safety issues. `  What are the issues?  This doesn't have to have issues. Can you make the `getClientA()` method `synchronized` ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: If two threads call `getClientA()` at the same time, both can perform the null check and create different instance of `ClientA`. There is then a race condition to determine which instance will be returned/stored internally.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - `synchronized` will work too. I was just wondering if there is some singleton pattern that can be applied in this case.

Comment: Why is a factory holding a reference to an object it constructed?

Comment: Doesn't this question belong on codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

`this.clientA = buildClientA(credentialService.getCredentials());` relies on the parameter `credentialService` passed to the constructor, not on the member `this.credentialService`. Therefore, the order of the initializations doesn't matter.

BTW, just to be safe and avoid confustion, I wouldn't use the same name for the parameter of the constructor and the member.

Comment: Me stupid! Didn't notice that. This should work too except in my question, I mentioned only one dependency while in real, I have multiple so would have to pass all of them around in build method. but that shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't save off a reference to the`CredentialService` as an instance variable, and continue passing `credentialService.getCredentials()` to `bulldClientA`. You are already not using the instance variable `credentialService`.

Answer (score 1):

What you call `ClientFactory` looks like it's really just a `ClientA`. So why not have a factory that depends on the credentials and share a reference to a `ClientA` if you want to avoid creating extra `ClientA` objects?

```
public class ClientFactory {
   private final CredentialService credentialService;

   public ClientFactory(CredentialService credentialService){
      this.credentialService = credentialService;
   }

   public ClientA newClientA(String credentials){
     return new ClientA(credentials);
   } 
}
```

If you want to have a pool of clients potentially, you can share a `Supplier<ClientA>` instead.

```
Supplier<ClientA> simpleSupplier = Suppliers.ofInstance(ClientFactory.newClientA()); // guava
Supplier<ClientA> allNewSupplier = () -> ClientFactory.newClientA(); // java 8 lambda
ClientA cachedClient = simpleSupplier.get();
ClientA newClient = allNewSupplier.get();
```

Comment: Good to know about `Supplier`. I'll see if I can make use of it.